# Finding consistent means of printing Leaflet.js map showing the right data

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, leaflet

I have a leaflet map that displays on a web page (html, css, jquery). This map displays a a widescreen Leaflet.js map and has on it some elements to form a featuregroup. There can be more than one group. When data is loaded the map does setbounds and centers in the middle of the map (and thus middle of the screen, too) on the object. However, the user can zoom, pan about and click on elements to see some information. This works great!

One of the reasons for creating this system is wanting to generate PDF documents. This includes other information on the page outside of the map, but also the map itself. Part of the purpose of doing this is to save having to manually create a PDF from a screenshot of the map and copying data.

This looks good in the print preview and saves to PDF well (using css print media to style it all), with the exception of one thing - the part of the map the print view is giving is from the left edge of the map. This means only the 25% left hand side of the map is shown in the print.

The print view takes the given size of the page element to determine how it displays on the print menu. For example, 25% width set means it's only 25% wide on the page.

As such, I'm not sure how else I can go from here where I keep the bounds around a featurLayer (or many, but don't need all of them in screen everytime), but move the view when the print window appears into such a position it captures the middle of the view, not the furthest left side (but restoring the view when the print dialog is closed, too!).

I've explored a few options of detecting when the print window has been opened, doing a panBy that's offset - however, this worked once when I left the elements on the map central. It does not work if you move the map prior, or the shape/size of these elements (they can be of vastly different sizes covering an area of anything from 100 meters to 10000 meters).
This is an example of what I got to work in the printer eventhandler, but is not dynamic enough for all cases;

```
var offsetx = map.getSize().x*0.33;
var offsety = map.getSize().y*0.1;
map.panBy(new L.Point(offsetx, offsety), {animate: false});
```

If I can just manipulate the view point of the map used in the printer preview and subsequent printing then that would work I think; but not sure if it is possible!